# How does a computer program recognize shocks given data of a solution to a conservation law?

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, na.numerical-analysis, entropy, numerical-analysis-of-pde, conservation-laws

Conservation laws are PDEs of the form $u_t +j_x=0.$ A discontinuous solution (for $u$ and $j$) to an equation like this can be easily found. Let's suppose that we are working with a piecewise constant solution $u$ with one shock with constant speed $\lambda.$ So there must be a discontinuity in $j$ as well.

My question is: given the data of such a discontinuous solution (a 2D array of the value of $u(x,t), j(x,t)$ at a finite selection of values of $x$ and $t$), how can a computer use the data to deduce that the solution is discontinuous?

Although the computer cannot know whether a function is continuous or not from value at finitely many points, it seems that **it should still be able to know that a shock exists in the solution.** I think this can be done because in many situations, **there does not exist a continuous solution** that approximates the given piecewise constant discontinuous solution above, for example **when the entropy is not conserved.** (We know that if we have an entropy function $\eta,$ then the conservation law $\eta_t+q_x =0$ may not hold in the sense of distributions for discontinuous solutions.)

But I struggle to see what's really going on. **The exact mechanism of the non-conservation of entropy at the shocks is a mystery.** I wish to understand it better.

Can anyone provide some reference/ideas for the problem I describe above? What's so special about the shocks?

Comment: The ideas you're looking for are covered in any text on numerical methods for hyperbolic conservation laws.  For instance, either of LeVeque's books.

Comment: This isn't an appropriate question for mathoverflow, since it is not a research question.  It would be more appropriate on scicomp.SE.  But if you really want to understand these things, read a book on the topic.